# Does resizing an STL vector erase/invalidate its previous contents?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

It doesn't appear to (sample program), but can I be sure?

```
// does resizing an STL vector erase/invalidate it's previous contents?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std ;

void print( vector<int>& t )
{
  for( int i = 0 ; i < t.size() ; i++ )
    printf( "%d ", t[i] ) ;
  puts("");
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> t ;
  t.resize( 12,9999 ) ;
  print(t) ;

  t.resize( 15, 10000 ) ;
  print(t) ;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "invalidate"?

Comment: @Xeo: For example, an "invalidated iterator" may not be accessed in a correct program.  Resizing a `std::vector` invalidates all of its iterators.  (Resizing a `std::list` does not.)

Comment: @Dietrich: I know about that, but the OP's code doesn't show any of that, so I was wondering what exactly "invalidated" means here. It could also be that the OP thought the previous items would be reset / erase / whatever'd.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Resizing an STL vector **may** require reallocating the underlying storage.  This **may** cause any number of elements to be destroyed and recreated, and **all iterators are invalidated.**  Accessing an invalidated iterator is a common source of errors when using the STL.

The **contents** of each element will be the same, unless the copy constructor doesn't work.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::vector vec(data, data + 3);
    // vector contains 1, 2, 3

    std::vector::iterator i = vec.begin();
    cout << *i << endl; // prints 1
    int &ref = *i;
    cout << ref << endl; // prints 1

    vec.resize(6, 99);
    // vector now contains 1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99

    // WRONG! may crash, may do the wrong thing, might work...
    // cout << *i << endl;

    // WRONG! invalid reference
    // cout << ref << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Specifically, if you resize a vector to a smaller size then only iterators to erased elements are invalidated. If you resize the vector to a larger size that is still less than the value of capacity() then no iterator invalidation occurs (it is prohibited by the standard). If you increase the size of the vector to be greater than the value of capacity then all iterators to elements of the vector are invalidated().

Comment: @Kemin: That is incorrect. Preserving the elements in a vector does not mean that the iterators are still valid after a resize. This is hinted at in the page you linked: "Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size because that would invalidate all iterators…" The fact is that *all* iterators are invalidated whenever the vector capacity changes, whether it gets larger or smaller. If you think about it, an iterator into a vector is basically just a pointer to an element, so of course it would be this way.

Comment: @Kemin: See the section named "iterator invalidation" in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector .  It's curious that the individual function pages don't mention invalidation, but it's clearly spelled out on the `std::vector` page that all iterators are invalidated by `resize` when the capacity changes.

Comment: Dietrich, you are correct. It is the value, but not the reference (pointers, iterators) that are reserved (moved to a different memory location). Sorry for the not being thorough.

Answer (score 9):

`resize` will invalidate all iterators, pointers, and references into the `std::vector` if and only if the new size is larger than the current capacity of the container (i.e., `v.capacity()`).

The *elements* in the container are never "invalidated."  If you resize the container to be smaller than its current size, any extra elements beyond the new size are destroyed.

If you resize the container such that the new size is larger than the current capacity and a reallocation of the underlying storage is required, all elements are copied or moved into newly-allocated storage.  When you enlarge a container, the previous elements are always retained, just moved or copied to new locations in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Resizing a vector doesn't destroy the values stored in the vector (except for those beyond the new size when shrinking, of course), however growing a vector beyond its capacity will copy (or, in C++11, move) them to a new place, thus invalidating and iterators, pointers or references to those elements.

In your example program you do not store iterators, pointers or references to vector elements during the resize, therefore you access the copied values if the data was copied during the resize (which is likely, but not completely certain; a vector may allocate space for more than the needed elements; indeed, when growing it often *must* do that in order to fulfill the complexity requirements).

You can get the current capacity (number of elements you can grow it to before reallocation is needed) through the member function `capacity`. As long as the vector doesn't grow beyond the current capacity, even iterators, pointers and references to the stored objects are safe. Also, if you want to make sure that no iterators, pointers or references are invalidated, and you know beforehand the maximal size to which the vector may grow, then you can preallocate all needed memory with the member function `reserve`.

Answer (score 0):

Resize copies the data for as much as fits. Take a look at this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/

Comment: Or look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize. The important thing is that it will copy insert if you make it bigger. Using reserved() is an option if you do not want to fill data yet. Only make space for new data.

Answer (score 0):

The contents will still be there.  If your vector has capacity 1000, with 500 elements in it, and you resize to 2000, all your 500 elements will be copied over.  If you resize it to 200, only the first 200 elements will be copied, and the last 300 will be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example **[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/)**.

When you resize to a larger size it just fills the new cells with the value.